# ASP.NET Core 2.1 code generation error - Multiple custom attributes of the same type found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a DbContext that contains several DbSets of classes, with some of the classes have properties of class types that are not specifically defined in the DbContext. The migration and the Database update work smoothly. However, when I try to use the code generation tool I get the error:

> Multiple custom attributes of the same type found.

First of all, I am not using any "Custom" attributes, only the following (and not on the same properties):

```
[ScaffoldColumn(true/false)]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress/PhoneNumber/Date/PostalCode/Password)]
[DisplayFormat]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "message.")]
[Phone(ErrorMessage = "A phone number is required")]
[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
```

I have too many lines of code to post here, but I can add some snippets if needed.

Comment: I see two `DataType` attributes in your code, is that intentional?

Comment: DataType attributes  are set to not be multiple.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick Just out of curiosity if I have a property that has been labeled with `[System.Linq.Mapping.Column]` and `[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Column]` does also apply in an exclusive fashion meaning I cannot use two attributes with the same name no matter which namespace because AllowMultiple = false on each?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used `DataType` twice. Choose whether you have a `DataType.EmailAddress/PhoneNumber/Date/PostalCode/Password` or a `DataType.PhoneNumber`.

```
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress/PhoneNumber/Date/PostalCode/Password)]
[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
```

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the right direction - I was using the [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)] attribute on the same property that I also used the [Phone] attribute. I quess they are mutually exclusive. Thanks...